# Apply inlay hints

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm missing the ability to apply the suggested inlay hint. All I can do is disable hints. This happened after the latest update; messing around for a while now. Has anyone solved this?

For some background;

[In typescript (Angular) you can add the type of the object as it's declared.](https://typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

For example, `let isDone = false;` with type would be: `let isDone: boolean = false;` Before the update, I could `cmd+shft+enter` and it would auto-fill `boolean`, in this example. Of course, pointless in this example, but on a massive app with loads of custom types it's a huge time saver.

[image: Example]

Comment: What do you mean with "apply the [..] inlay hint"? As far as I'm aware, the inlay hints are simply text rendered to show variable names, etc. to improve readability, they have - AFAIK - no further functionality, so maybe you're actually looking for something else.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for the reply. 

It used to allow me to apply the hint... I'm starting to wonder if it was a plugin now :/

Comment: It might be helpful to describe the effects of the function you're looking for. Maybe it clicks with someone (and I could be wrong, I generally use IntelliJ with Java, and I disable the inlay hints as I find them distracting ;)

Comment: okay, so in typescript (Angular) you can add the type of the object as its declared. 

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

For example

`let isDone = false;`  with type would be: `let isDone: boolean = false;`

Before the update, I could `cmd+shft+enter` and it would auto fill boolean, in this example. Of course, pointless in this example, but on a massive app with loads of these custom types its a huge time saver

Comment: I suggest you edit that into your question.